# vc++ graphic performance

Tags: visual-c++, graphics, mfc, wtl

I want to build a obj to draw a realtime graph but I have performance limitations
size of graph is static.

in repaint the graph 
I can redraw all the needed line.
I have other way that save the graph on bitmap memory 
and each time copy it on the screen
which way is better?
what is faster copy bitmap or draw lines?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on what you are trying to display. Showing a few lines should not pose any performance problems (if done well), but doing anything more graphics-intensive can be more problematic.

It also depends on what you use for drawing. GDI is easy but slow; GDI+ is also easy, can be prettier (antialiasing, etc.) but is also quite slow (or used to be when I tried it); OpenGL is fast but a bit trickier.

So it's a question with no easy answer, not knowing all the details of your needs. I think I would draw directly, and if it's not fast enough then check other options. What you'll probably need anyway is a double-buffering system, to avoid flickering (check http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/flickerfree.aspx)

You can take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/High-speedCharting.aspx. It's a charting control which seems to be quite fast.